# Which is the best practice for saving a price column on PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am currently developing an e-commerce system, and for now, I'm using the type numeric to save the price of the products on my database.
I want to know if this is the best practice or if I should use double-precision or another type.

Comment: [Don't use money](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Numeric` is the best practice for storing prices.

In general, you want to avoid floating point representations for numbers because they can have rounding errors and precision errors -- that might add up over large quantities of numbers.